# How to prove 2>1?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

How to prove that $$2>1$$
May be some set/analytic theory is used?
I heard about that but I just cannot do it?
I attempted to google it but I don't see any relevant results.

Comment: What is your definition of $2$, $1$ and $>$?

Comment: What happen if $2\le 1$?

Answer (score 2):

Let us review the relevant axioms of Peano Arithmetic. There are a few more, concerning multiplication and induction.  Let $S(x)=x+1$ be the successor function.

> 1. Zero isn't the successor of any number.
> 2. $S(m)=S(n)$ implies $m=n$.
> 3. $n+0=n$
> 4. $n+S(m)=S(n+m)$

Now we define $>$ as the following. This is just one of the possible definitions.

> 1. $S(a) > a$ for all $a$.
> 2. If $a>b$ and $b>c$ then $a>c$.

Let us now define $1$ and $2$. $1$ is the shorthand for  $S(0)$. $2$ is the shorthand for $S(S(0))$. By definition we have now $2=S(S(0))>S(0)=1$. If you give me your definition of $>$, I may give another proof.

Comment: This question is tagged real-analysis, so the OP probably doesn't want integer answers, I think.

Answer (score 0):

There is a major obstacle to giving an answer because there is no definition of $>,1,2 \cdots$

Nevertheless, this is my answer:

Assume that $1,2 \in \mathbb{R}$ and $+, \times$ are defined as usual in $\mathbb{R}$

First, Let $P$ is the subset of $\mathbb{R}$ such that

1) If $a,b \in P$, then $a+b, ab \in P$

2) $\mathbb{R}=P \cup -P \cup {0}$ where $-P=\{-a : a \in P\}$

3) P, -P, {0} are pairwise disjoint

Then define the relation $>$ as "$a>b $ means that $a-b \in P$".

Since 2-1=1 (there are so many gaps!), now we want to show that $1 \in P$.

By field axiom $1 \ne 0$.

Presume that $1 \in -P$ , then $-1 \in P$.

$\Rightarrow (-1)(-1)=1 \in P$

$\Rightarrow 1\in P \cap -P$

This is contradiction.

Thus, $1 \in P$. It means $2>1$

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you define $1, 2$ and $<$, but after you choose which $1$'s, $2$'s and $<$'s you are dealing with, the proof is easy (as expected).

Natural numbers, version 1: one defines $\mathbb{N}$ by recursion by saying that $0 = \varnothing$, $n = (n-1) \cup \{n-1\} $, from which we define $n<m \iff n \subset m $.

In this case we have $1=\{ \varnothing \} $ and $ 2 = \{ \varnothing , \{ \varnothing \} \}$; since $ 1 \subset 2$ we conclude that $1 < 2$.

Natural numbers, version 2: using Peano axioms, as stated in the answer by withagoras.

Integer numbers, Rational numbers: just prove it using their definitions as classes of equivalence.

Real numbers, version 1: the set $\mathbb{R}$ of real numbers can be defined using Dedekind's cuts (take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Construction_of_the_real_numbers); the nice part of this construction is that we have again $a < b \iff a \subset b$.

Now, $1 = \{q \in \mathbb{Q}: q<1\} $ and $2=\{q \in \mathbb{Q}: q<2\} $ and we have that $1 \subset 2$ (as real numbers) because $1 < 2$ (as rational numbers).

Real numbers, version 2: one can also use the axiomatic definition of $\mathbb{R}$, defined as the complete ordered field (which is unique up to isomorphism); again take a look at the linked Wikipedia page.
Now we have $1>0$ because $1$ is a square and hence $ 2 = 1 + 1 > 0 +1 = 1$.